# Get the checkbox in which div was clicked using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, onclick

If I have two `div`s with checkboxes in each of them, how can I find out which `checkbox` in which div was clicked?

```html
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
  <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
  <br>
</div>
```

I would be grateful if you advise me on a method that uses JS **(not jQuery)**.

Comment: Do you have a `<div>` around all the `#num-x` `<div>`s? That will make it easier.

Comment: You can give your input a different name. Then you can check the different name value.

Comment: @Xufox Yes, I can add it.

Comment: If you haven't written a single line of JavaScript yet, this question is too broad. Just the code for event handlers can be rather lengthy depending on your cross-browser needs.

Comment: Wow, 10 answers in 16 minutes… this is definitely not enough research effort.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use event delegation and name attribute. Once your target is the checkbox you can access anything from this object including it's value, name or if it's selected or not

```js
document.querySelector('.someform').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler(e) {        
    var input = e.path.filter(function (x) {return x.type === 'checkbox'});

    if(input.length) {
        console.log(input.pop().parentNode);
    }

}
```

```html
<form class="someform">
<div id="num-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1"> Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1" <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-2" value="check-1"> Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2" <br>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: You should probably filter out the label being clicked.

Comment: @seth yes this can be made more robust if an if statement or filtering out the path object given by the browser to the div in question. But as it stands it definitely answers the question

Comment: _But as it stands it definitely answers the question_, that answer your version of the question using form, what if he can't/don't want to add form?

Comment: Valid response. These elements have parent(s) no matter where they are placed inside of document. By using event delegation you will receive a lot of benefits for free. It would be best to still attach the listener on the parent that encapsulates all of these elements, then adjust your selector accordingly

Comment: I know what the event delegation is for... you could see that i'm using it in my answer. your answer is not an efficient/valid response until you add condition on clicked element since when you click on the label of checkbox you will get `<form class="someform">…</form>` and not the direct parent of checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

**Using `jQuery`(though it is not tagged!)**

Use `.closest` with [**`Attribute Starts With Selector`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```js
$('[type="checkbox"][name^="check-"]').on('change', function() {
  console.log($(this).closest('div[id^="num-"]').get(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
  <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
  <br>
</div>
```

**Using VanillaJS**

- Use `document.querySelectorAll` to select `type="checkbox"` elements
- Use `[].foreach.call` to iterate `array-like` object(having `length` property)
- Use `addEventListener` to attach `change` event
- `Element.parentNode` will return `parent-element` of the current element

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('[type="checkbox"]');
[].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
  el.addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.parentNode);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
  <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't think this code complies with the *Not jQuery* part of the question ;-)

Comment: Ignore that! I didn't notice that you later provided the actual answer :)

Answer (score 1):

That can be achieved using different way, I suggest to not define the callback function inside the loop because that will define it several time (in every iteration), so you could declare it one time out of the loop then attach the click (or change) event using event delegation `addEventListener()` to the checkboxes using the `name` attribute `check-1` :

```
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check-1');

for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getParent);
  //checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change', getParent);
}
```

Then you have to define the function that will be triggered every time the user `click/change` on checkboxes (`getParent()` in my example) and inside this function you could use `.parentNode` method plus `.id` to get `id` attribute of the parent div :

```
function getParent(){
  alert(this.parentNode.id);
}
```

```js
var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('check-1');

for(var i=0;i<checkboxes.length;i++){
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', getParent);
}

function getParent(){
  alert(this.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1"> Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1" <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1"> Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2" <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `parentElement` property of the clicked checkbox, like this:

```js
function detectDiv(obj) {
  var parent = obj.parentElement;
  console.log(parent.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="num-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1" onclick="detectDiv(this)"> Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1" <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1" onclick="detectDiv(this)"> Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2" <br>
</div>
```

Comment: hey @ADreNaLiNe-DJ correct the variable name please, this doesn't execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll()` and `for` loop and return `parentNode` which is `div`

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  inputs[i].addEventListener('change', function() {
    console.log(this.parentNode.id);
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
  <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add an click- or change handler which takes the checkbox as argument, and then navigate to the parent node.

Example:

```
function checkboxChange(checkbox) {
    console.log(checkbox.parentNode.id);
}
```

html:

```
<div id="num-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1" onchange="checkboxChange(this)"> Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1" <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1" onchange="checkboxChange(this)"> Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2" <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `<div>` around all the `#num-x` `<div>`s, you can use event delegation to figure out which checkbox has been clicked and then get its parent:

```js
document.getElementById("num-container").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(e.target.type == "checkbox"){
    console.log("Parent div:", e.target.parentNode, "Checked?", e.target.checked);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="num-container">
  <div id="num-1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
    <br>
  </div>

  <div id="num-2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The example below will log the `id` value for each input, when clicked.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
  input.addEventListener('click', findParent);
});

function findParent() {
  console.log(this.parentNode.id);
}
```

```html
<div id="num-1">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1"
  <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
  <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
  <br>
</div>
```

To break it down step-by-step...

First you use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and pass in the input selector to get all desired inputs in a [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). We will save this to `var inputs`.

(My suggestion would be, if you have control of your markup, to use a shared class for each input so you're not targeting **all** inputs)

Then you loop through each node by calling the [`Array` prototype of `forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on the `inputs` [`nodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList), which allows you to iterate over each node(input). While in the iteration, you add an [`eventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your input and issue a callback function to fire upon the event being dispatched.

Inside your callback function, target the input's [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode), which returns the first ascending node in the DOM. Finally, to get the input's id, you simply use `.id`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure JavaScript solution :

```
// HTML code 
<div id="num-1">
<input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1"> Checkbox "check-1" of the Div "num-1" <br>
</div>

<div id="num-2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="check-1" value="check-1">Checkbox "check-2" of the Div "num-2"
    <br>
  </div>

// javascript code 
checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');

for(var i=0;i < checkboxes.length;i++){
  // add event listener for each input element
  checkboxes[i].addEventListener('change',function(e){
    console.log(this.parentElement); // will log the direct parent
  });
}
```